# Finding the user's directory using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ionic-framework

So I am writing a script to automate some things that me and my teammates do. We have a git repo and this script is intended for all members to use. It has a part that is hardcoded to specifically be my folder path: `C:/Users/jorge.padilla/etc...`

I am still relatively new to python and not familiar with all the different libraries. I basically want to turn the user directory, i.e. jorge.padilla, into a variable that is not hardcoded, and that doesn't need to take user input so that the script will search for whatever the current user directory is and substitute it.

Below is a small snippet of the automation script I am writing to use as an example.

```
import os, sys
from pathlib import Path
from enum import Enum

#Global Variables
PRODUCTS_FOLDER = "Products"
APP_FOLDER = "App"
DEV_BUILD = "ionic cordova build android"
PROD_BUILD = "ionic cordova build android --release --prod"

class BuildConfig():
    def __init__(self, start_path):
        self.start_path = start_path

    def getProductFolder(self):
        return os.path.join(self.start_path, PRODUCTS_FOLDER)

class BuildTypeEnum(Enum):
    PROD = 1
    DEV = 2

def buildingApp(ConfigPath:BuildConfig, DEVvPROD:BuildTypeEnum):
    path = ConfigPath.getProductFolder()
    app_path = os.path.join(path, APP_FOLDER)
    os.chdir(app_path)
    if DEVvPROD == BuildTypeEnum.DEV:
        os.system(DEV_BUILD)
    elif DEVvPROD == BuildTypeEnum.PROD: 
        os.system(PROD_BUILD)
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root_start_path = "C:/Users/jorge.padilla/Documents/"
    build = BuildConfig(root_start_path)

    buildType = None
    buildTypeInput = input("Is this a dev or production build? (d/p): ")
    if (buildTypeInput.lower() == 'd'):
        buildType = BuildTypeEnum.DEV
    elif (buildTypeInput.lower() == 'p'):
        buildType = BuildTypeEnum.PROD
    else:
        print("Please specify if this is a development or production build.")
        return
```

The main variable I want to do this for is `root_start_path`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.home) (which you imported, but never used?):

```
import pathlib
root_start_path = pathlib.Path.home()  # WindowsPath('C:/Users/jorge.padilla')
```

It works across platforms as well, and it's really the best way to handle file paths (IMO)

It can even simplify the syntax in accessing other directories within that path:

```
root_start_path = pathlib.Path.home() / 'Documents'  # WindowsPath('C:/Users/jorge.padilla/Documents')
```

Comment: `.home()` is a classmethod and thus you do not need to instantiate `Path` first - so `pathlib.Path.home()` works just fine.

Comment: is that an overloaded / division operator to add folders to the string? neat.

Comment: @PatrickArtner it is, and it's a super convinient method to avoid using `os.path.join` or `Path().joinpath` all together

Comment: Thank you for the comments. This is super helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
    from os.path import expanduser
    home = expanduser("~")
```

Comment: Expanduser is a function that returns the argument with an initial component of ~ or ~user replaced by that user’s home directory. It is pretty thoroughly explained in: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html